# Inject a class which provides the services to ProjectDao

Tags: java, dao, business-logic

I have got a class which behaves as a center of API services. I need to use one of the services in this class to filter out the result from database query.

Is it a good practice for me to inject this service class into a ProjectDaoImpl class?

I am asking this because I have found some examples which only use the service at business logic level (eg ProjectLogicImpl) but not in DAO level.

Comment: Do you mean the Services class? No it consists of methods such as getCurrentUserId, getSuperUser, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a good practice. The service layer should depend on the DAO layer, but the reverse should not be true. But you may have a DAOHelperService object in the DAO layer that is injected in DAOs and in services. That wouldn't break proper layering.